# Dividir (sacar promedio) entre campos en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Estoy iniciándome en programación y base de datos y tengo una duda respecto a MongoDB con [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

Estoy intentando sacar el promedio de edades en mi colección, pero no logro hacerlo.

COLECCIÓN PRODUCTOS (2 docs):

```
/* 1 createdAt:1/12/2020 20:55:27*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc6d7ef28a153035af0282e"),
    "nombre" : "prestamo joven",
    "montoMaximo" : 300000,
    "edadMaxima" : 30
},

/* 2 createdAt:1/12/2020 20:56:17*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc6d82128a153035af0282f"),
    "nombre" : "prestamo adultos",
    "montoMaximo" : 300000,
    "edadMinima" : 31
}
```

COLECCIÓN SOLICITUDES (100 docs):

Dejo dos ejemplos:

```
/* 1 createdAt:1/12/2020 22:31:46*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc6ee8228a153035af029d4"),
    "nombreCompleto" : "Nombre Completo de persona que solicita producto joven",
    "fechaSolicitud" : ISODate("2020-12-01T22:31:46.035-03:00"),
    "productoSolicitado" : ObjectId("5fc6d7ef28a153035af0282e"),
    "edad" : 27,
    "montoSolicitado" : 84906
},

/* 4 createdAt:1/12/2020 22:31:46*/
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fc6ee8228a153035af02a0f"),
    "nombreCompleto" : "Error encontrado",
    "fechaSolicitud" : ISODate("2020-12-01T22:31:46.196-03:00"),
    "productoSolicitado" : ObjectId("5fc6d82128a153035af0282f"),
    "edad" : 26,
    "montoSolicitado" : 275237
}
```

El campo "productoSolicitado" en solicictudes es el `_id` de alguno de los dos documentos de la colección “productos”.

CÓDIGO:

```
db.getCollection("solicitudes").aggregate([
    
    { $lookup:{
        
        from: "productos",
        localField: "productoSolicitado",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "productos_lookup" }},
        
    { $match: {
        "edad": {$lte: 30},
        "montoSolicitado": {$lte: 300000},
        "productos_lookup.nombre": "prestamo joven" }},

   /* { $project: {
        "_id":1,
        "nombreCompleto":1,
        "edad" : 1,
        "montoSolicitado":1,
        "productos_lookup.nombre":1 }}, */
    
    { $group: {
        _id: "",
        sumaEdad: {$sum: "$edad"},
        "contarResultados": {"$sum": 1} }},
    
    ])
```

RESULTADO DEL CÓDIGO:

```
{
    "_id" : "",
    "sumaEdad" : 69,
    "contarResultados" : 3
}
```

Quiero dividir "sumaEdad" : 69, sobre "contarResultados" : 3 para sacer el promedio de las edades

Intente lo siguiente agregando esto dentro de $group:

```
{ "$prom": [ {"$sumaEdad" / "$contarResultados"}] }
```

No funciona

Probé crear una variable con `js`:

```
var prom = $sumaEdad / $contarResultados
```

No funciona

Les agradecería si pueden ayudarme ya que como mencioné, soy novato y estoy intentando aprender.

Comment: ¿Has intentado usar [$avg](https://sodocumentation.net/es/mongodb/topic/3852/agregacion#promedio) directamente?

Answer (score 1):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea calcular el promedio de edad de un campo de tipo numérico en una colección de MongoDB, la cual es filtrada de acuerdo a ciertos parámetros en un proceso de agregación. El resultado final esperado es el promedio de dicho campo.

Tal como te han [comentado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414115/devidir-entre-campos-en-mongodb#comment739635_414115), podrías usar el operador [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) para calcular el promedio de edad de acuerdo al patrón de filtrado de tu agregación.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Una solución al problema es utilizar el operador [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#grp._S_avg) dentro de una etapa [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group), esto nos devolvería el valor del promedio calculado agrupado por cierto campo, el cual podría ser el valor del campo `productoSolicitado`.

Por ejemplo, la siguiente consulta de agregación aplicada sobre la colección de `solicitudes` devolvería el resultado antes planteado:

```js
db.solicitudes.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "productos",
      "localField": "productoSolicitado",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "productos"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "edad": {
        "$lte": 30
      },
      "montoSolicitado": {
        "$lte": 300000
      },
      "productos.nombre": "prestamo joven"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$productoSolicitado",
      "promedioEdad": {
        "$avg": "$edad"
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Mostrando un resultado parecido al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5fdb221b1a4f5d08bae3d530"),
    "promedioEdad": 23.166666666666668
  }
]
```

Dependerá de la información que deseamos como salida, lo que vamos a agregar en el la etapa `$group`. Por ejemplo, si deseamos el nombre del producto o algún otro dato, podríamos agregar lo siguiente:

```js
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$productoSolicitado",
    "nombreProducto": {
      "$last": "$productos.nombre"
    },
    "promedioEdad": {
      "$avg": "$edad"
    }
  }
}
```

Cuyo resultado podría verse así:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5fdb221b1a4f5d08bae3d530"),
    "nombreProducto": [
      "prestamo joven"
    ],
    "promedioEdad": 23.166666666666668
  }
]
```

Incluso si no deseamos que el campo `nombreProducto` sea un `Array`, podemos aplicar una etapa [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) previa para crear documentos con campo `productos` que no sea un `Array`:

```js
// Usamos $unwind
{
  "$unwind": "$productos"
},
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$productoSolicitado",
    "nombreProducto": {
      "$last": "$productos.nombre"
    },
    "promedioEdad": {
      "$avg": "$edad"
    }
  }
}
```

Siendo el resultado final, parecido a:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5fdb221b1a4f5d08bae3d530"),
    "nombreProducto": "prestamo joven",
    "promedioEdad": 23.166666666666668
  }
]
```

En el cual estamos devolviendo el valor `_id` del producto, el nombre del producto y el promedio de edad de las solicitudes de dicho producto. Aún si quisiéramos añadir la cantidad de solicitudes, basta con agregar otro acumulador a la etapa `$group`, por ejemplo:

```js
{
  "$group": {
    "_id": "$productoSolicitado",
    "nombreProducto": {
      "$last": "$productos.nombre"
    },
    "promedioEdad": {
      "$avg": "$edad"
    },
    "cantidadSolicitudes": {
      "$sum": 1
    }
  }
}
```

Lo cual nos devuelve:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5fdb221b1a4f5d08bae3d530"),
    "cantidadSolicitudes": 6,
    "nombreProducto": "prestamo joven",
    "promedioEdad": 23.166666666666668
  }
]
```

Lo que indica que de las 100 (o la cantidad de solicitudes de tu colección) al menos 6 cumplen los criterios del filtro.

En el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3up1kNycCTk) se muestra el proceso anterior, donde se generan 100 solicitudes de forma aleatoria y se filtra el resultado usando el proceso de agregación antes explicado.

Como se observa el valor del promedio de edad es un tipo *flotante*, no es necesario redondearlo, pero en caso de que lo desees redondeado, puedes usar el operador [`$round`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/round/index.html) dentro de una etapa [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project). **Para esto debes disponer de MongoDB 4.2 o superior.**

Por ejemplo:

```js
{
  "$project": {
    "nombreProducto": 1,
    "cantidadSolicitudes": 1,
    "promedioEdad": {
      "$round": [
        "$promedioEdad",
        2
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Lo cual produce un resultado parecido al siguiente:

```js
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5fdb221b1a4f5d08bae3d530"),
    "cantidadSolicitudes": 6,
    "nombreProducto": "prestamo joven",
    "promedioEdad": 23.17
  }
]
```

Donde se observa que el promedio de edad fue redondeado a 2 decimales. Puedes observar el resultado en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nmnwhAIO0qy).

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo y el trabajo de explicarme todo esto de forma tan clara, muchísimas gracias. Me ha sido muy útil toda esta información.